# UIButton outside of UIView (xib) frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, xib

I have a custom `UIView XIB` that gets loaded onto my `ViewController` and the frame is adjusted to be collapsed before added to subview. The UIButton tied to my `XIB` is showing when the frame is smaller than the button location. How can I hide and show my UIButton as the frame is expanding/collapsing? My XIB is not using `AutoLayout`.

ViewController.m

```
self.greenView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Green" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.greenView];
```

GreenView.h

```
@interface GreenView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *expandView;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isExpanded) BOOL expand;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *testButton;
- (IBAction)testButtonTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

GreenView.m

```
@interface GreenView()
@property (nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;
@end

@implementation GreenView
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.expandView.frame.size.height;
    frame.origin.y = 200;
    self.frame = frame;
    self.expand = NO;
    [self.expandView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGesture];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    if (!_tapGesture) {
        _tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapClicked:)];
    }
    return _tapGesture;
}

- (void)tapClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    self.expand = !self.expand;
    frame.size.height = self.expand ? gvExpandedHeight : gvCollapsedHeight;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Frame after animation: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    }];
}

- (IBAction)testButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Test button tapped");
}
@end
```

Collapsed:

[image: Collapsed]

Expanded:

[image: Expanded]

GreenView.xib:

[image: GreenView.xib]

GrenenView.xib Struts and Springs:

[image: Struts and springs of greenview.xib]

Comment: I did not recognize any question. Please update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you just want to clip it, if the button is outside to the view bounds. In `-awakeFromNib` add:

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Using this property you are telling the view to cut everything that is not inside its bounds, views caw draw subviews even if they are place outside. Is a little expensive by means of performance, if you use it a lot or during heavy animations.
One way around could be hide it while the view is collapsed.

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked perfect! I thought about hiding it while collapsed but couldn't find a smooth transition into showing it. Changing the alpha worked but I didn't really like it. This will be the only view on my controller needing `clipsToBounds`

Answer (score 0):

You change the frame to `frame.origin.y = 200;`

I think you have to set the `UIButton` constraint relative to your `GreenView` in you nib file

Comment: Updated my post. Added images my XIB file. My UIButton is tied to my XIB because I would like it to show when expanded but hidden when collapsed.